# Get BackBuffer from RenderTargetBitmap?

Tags: c#

So I have a usercontrol in a class. In the program which is using the class, it will render the usercontrol as a bitmap, and then display the user control as the image source.

Normally I would do this as follows:

```
private MyUserControl userControl;
private RenderTargetBitmap bitmap;
private WriteableBitmap wBitmap;

public MyClass()
{
    bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(1280, 40, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
}

private void renderBitmap()
{
    bitmap.Clear();
    bitmap.Render(textControl);
    wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

    texture.SetImage(wBitmap.BackBuffer);
}

private delegate void TickDelegate();
override public void Tick(float fSeconds)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new TickDelegate(renderBitmap));
}
```

As you can see, the `SetImage` function requires the backbuffer from a writeablebitmap. However, there is a problem with this. My usercontrol has animations in it; so this function is executed about 30 times a second. This all works, the animations are displayed in the program exactly how I want it to.

The issue is that with `new WriteableBitmap()` being called 30 times a second, and this consumes a TON of memory. Is there a way I can set my `RenderTargetBitmap` to my `WriteableBitmap` without having to declare a `new WriteableBitmap()` 30 times a second? Or possibly get a backbuffer from `RenderTargetBitmap` without having to use `WriteableBitmap`?

- EDIT *

Okay, apparently I can add the following after the texture is set:

```
wBitmap = null;
GC.Collect();
```

This prevents the massive spike in memory usage. However, is there harm in calling the garbage collector 30 times a second?

Comment: Your title does not match the question. It asks about getting a backbuffer, but your question makes clear you already know how to do that and are instead asking about the GC, something the title does not mention at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you didn't show your complete code so I don't know what `texture` is. But I'm assuming that once you set the `BackBuffer` object for it, it always will reflect any updates to the `BackBuffer` object. With that in mind...

Instead of creating a new `WriteableBitmap` object every tick, create just one for use with the texture. Then use `BitmapSource.CopyPixels()` to get the result of your call to `Render()`, then finally use `WriteableBitmap.WritePixels()` to copy that back to the `WriteableBitmap`.

Remember to call `Lock` and `Unlock` around your update of the `WriteableBitmap`.

With that approach, you would avoid creating a large number of new bitmap objects dozens of times per second.

Comment: Maybe you've already figured this out. But if you post a true concise-but-complete code example that reliably demonstrates the original issue, I don't mind modifying it to accomplish the above. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some guidelines for what I mean by that.

Comment: Thanks, but I figured it out using AddDirtyRect, instead of WritePixels.